# What are all those partition table type in gparted?

Tags: partitioning, mbr, gpt, gparted

I was just curious about what are those available partition table types in gparted useful for. Is there any reason to use them instead of MBR or GPT ?

- atari
- aix
- amiga
- bsd
- dvh
- mac
- pc98
- sun

Comment: Judging by the names they are useful types for other OSes that use them ...

Comment: I also see `msdos`, and it's the default inthe `gparted` that shipped with Ubuntu Budgie 18.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/289389/what-are-the-differences-between-the-various-partition-tables corresponding question

Answer (score 16, accepted):

#### What are those available partition table types in `gparted` useful for?

The options you mention (other than Atari) are covered below (and I guess Atari is there to support Atari partition tables).

> The options correspond to the various partitioning systems supported
>   in [`libparted`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/86440/stephen-kitt); there's not [much documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/parted/manual/html_node/mklabel.html#mklabel), but looking
>   at [the source code](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/parted.git/tree/libparted/labels):
>
> - `aix` provides support for the volumes used in IBM’s AIX (which introduced what we now know as LVM);
> - `amiga` provides support for the Amiga’s RDB partitioning scheme;
> - `bsd` provides support for BSD disk labels;
> - `dvh` provides support for SGI disk volume headers;
> - `gpt` provides support for GUID partition tables;
> - `mac` provides support for old (pre-GPT) Apple partition tables;
> - `msdos` provides support for DOS-style MBR partition tables;
> - `pc98` provides support for [PC-98](http://people.freebsd.org/~kato/pc98.html) partition tables;
> - `sun` provides support for Sun’s partitioning scheme;
> - `loop` provides support for raw disk access (loopback-style) — I’m not sure about the uses for this one.
>
> As you can see, the majority of these are for older systems, and you
>   probably won’t need to create a partition table of any type other than
>   `gpt` or `msdos`.
>
> For a new disk, **I recommend `gpt`**: it allows more partitions, it
>   can be booted even in pre-UEFI systems (using `grub`), and supports
>   disks larger than 2 TiB (up to 8 ZiB for 512-byte sector disks).
>   Actually, if you don’t need to boot from the disk, I’d recommend not
>   using a partitioning scheme at all and simply adding the whole disk to
>   `mdadm`, LVM, or a zpool, depending on whether you use LVM (on top of
>   `mdadm` or not) or ZFS.

Source [What are the differences between the various partition tables?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/289401), answer by [Stephen Kitt](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/86440/stephen-kitt)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So back then every computer manufacturer made their own partition table type ?

Comment: @Nicryc Yes. Things were not so standardised in the olden days :)